# What are some good feeds/blogs/twitter accounts to follow if I want to learn more about web development?

Tags: blog, twitter, learning, resources, rss

Who are some of the big names out there (besides [Jeff Atwood](http://codinghorror.com)/[@codinghorror](http://twitter.com/codinghorror), of course) that I should be following as a resource if I want to stay on top of what's new as well commentary on what exists?

***Please consider simply editing this question, rather than posting another answer if you have something to add that is not listed here. Additionally, feel free to add descriptions to items already listed.***

Twitter accounts:

- [@codinghorror](http://twitter.com/codinghorror)
- [@smashingmag](http://twitter.com/smashingmag)
- [@shanselman](http://twitter.com/shanselman)
- [@scottgu](http://twitter.com/scottgu)
- [@haacked](http://twitter.com/haacked)
- [@jquery](http://twitter.com/jquery)
- [@jeresig](http://twitter.com/jeresig)
- [@slicknet](http://twitter.com/slicknet)
- [@paul_irish](http://twitter.com/paul_irish)
- [@trentwalton](http://twitter.com/trentwalton)
- [@sarajchipps](http://twitter.com/sarajchipps)
- [@DanEnglishby](https://twitter.com/DanEnglishby)

Blogs:

- [Coding Horror](http://codinghorror.com)
- [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com)
- [Fabulous Adventures in Coding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/)
- [StackOverflow Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/)
- [FriendlyBit](http://friendlybit.com/)
- [Fiftyfoureleven](http://www.fiftyfoureleven.com/)
- [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/)
- [Code Wall](https://www.codewall.co.uk/)

Feeds:

- [Reddit Programming Feed](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/)
- [Y Combinator](http://news.ycombinator.com/)

Comment: Shouldn't this be community wiki? Just going to be a massive list.

Comment: Isn't this (a) subjective, and (b) more appropriate for SO (code) and Doctype (design)?

Comment: made it community wiki and compiled some of the answers

Answer (score 6):

[@smashingmag](http://twitter.com/smashingmag) is a great Twitter feed, they regularly post links to interesting blog articles.

Comment: Yup. Their Twittr account more so than thir blog in my exprience.

Comment: Their twitter is really really good.

Answer (score 4):

I can't believe I will be the first one to post this:

http://www.alistapart.com/

Answer (score 2):

Primarily for the MS Web Devs out there:
[@shanselman](http://twitter.com/shanselman)
[@scottgu](http://twitter.com/scottgu)
[@haacked](http://twitter.com/haacked)

Answer (score 1):

http://news.ycombinator.com/ (Hacker News) is my all-time favorite.

Comment: while I frequent hacker new I wouldn't say its a "web development" community, although sometimes a web dev topic floats up.

Answer (score 1):

A few good web peeps that I follow are:

- @elijahmanor
- @jquery
- @smashingmag
- @Web_Dev_Links
- @shanselman
- @jeresig
- @reybango
- @nettuts

I have a [tech list](http://twitter.com/CoryMathews/tech) that can get your started Its mostly web but a few other general tech twitter users.

Answer (score 1):

[The Web Design Subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/web_design) has lots of good information.

Answer (score 0):

I find some good stuff on [friendlybit](http://friendlybit.com/), also checkout [The stackoverflow blog and podcasts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/) for more general discussion and advanced topics.

Answer (score 0):

See more answers here [Best Programming Blogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78955/what-are-the-best-programming-and-development-related-blogs) and look for web-related programming

- [Reddit Programming feed](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/)
- [Favorite Website Awards](http://www.thefwa.com/) for web development inspiration and links to other blogs

Answer (score 0):

@cssglobe css related awesomeness
@SohTanaka drupal, jQuery, CSS, php you name it. Awesome website too.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sitepoint.com/ is an excellent website/blog for learning about web development.

Answer (score 0):

For ColdFusion:
 @cfjedimaster
 @clarkee21
 @JasonPDean
 @seancorfield

For UI Design:
 @cameronmoll
 @drawr
 @khoi
 @andyrutledge

Answer (score 0):

THINKVITAMIN is one of the best I know. They have boatloads of useful HTML,CSS and Javascript articles. They tend to focus on design, but also have many useful inspiring articles about starting a business, managing your time and so on. They don't add articles too often, but they have nice "roundup" posts with news from around the web.

A LIST APART adds articles far less often, but at least you have the time to digest them ;)  It's a lot more focused on HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Steve Souders's blog about HIGHPERFORMANCE WEBSITES.

JSMAG BLOG feed is quite nice to stay up to date on Javascript news.

Comment: you should put some links on here so i can add them to the list

Comment: Yeah, only I'm told I can't because I don't have enough "e penis" yet. Oh, and you didn't even Google these up? Are you working on your e-penis too or were you looking for answers? ADMIN NOTE: CAN YOU PLEASE DELETE MY ACCOUNT.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a C# developer then I'd highly recommend reading Eric Lippert's blog [Fabulous Adventures In Coding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/). He's a "*a senior developer on the Microsoft Visual C# compiler team*" and therefore has unprecedented knowledge about the language and programming in general. His incite and experience is always stunning. He's also [active on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert), too, where his answers are always authoritative and often fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

For CodeIgniter / Expression Engine users and developers I found [@CodeignitEE](http://twitter.com/codeignitee) to be a valuable resource.